# How can I set a cloudformation field with function shorthand (ie. !Sub) using yq?

Tags: aws-cloudformation, jq, yq

I need to add a managed policy to a large number of lambda and ecs task roles across many cloudformation yaml files. Some of them already have this array field with items in it while some do not. I need to add an item to the ManagedPolicyArns array field where that item contains cloudformation shorthand such as !Sub. I'm using yq, which is a fantastic tool, but I can't figure out handling this shorthand using the docs.

cloudformation.yaml:

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: "2010-09-09"
Parameters:
  MyPrefix:
    Description: MyPrefix
    Type: String
Resources:
  MyRole:
    Type: AWS::IAM::Role
    Properties:
      ManagedPolicyArns:
        - Fn::ImportValue: !Sub "${MyPrefix}-my-policy-arn"
      AssumeRolePolicyDocument:
        Version: '2012-10-17'
        Statement:
          - Effect: Allow
            Principal:
              Service:
                - ecs-tasks.amazonaws.com
                - lambda.amazonaws.com
            Action:
              - sts:AssumeRole
              - sts:TagSession
      Path: /
```

Expected output .yaml:

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: "2010-09-09"
Parameters:
  MyPrefix:
    Description: MyPrefix
    Type: String
Resources:
  MyRole:
    Type: AWS::IAM::Role
    Properties:
      ManagedPolicyArns:
        - Fn::ImportValue: !Sub "${MyPrefix}-my-policy-arn"
        - Fn::ImportValue: !Sub "${MyPrefix}-my-new-policy-arn"
      AssumeRolePolicyDocument:
        Version: '2012-10-17'
        Statement:
          - Effect: Allow
            Principal:
              Service:
                - ecs-tasks.amazonaws.com
                - lambda.amazonaws.com
            Action:
              - sts:AssumeRole
              - sts:TagSession
      Path: /
```

My failed attempt:

add_policy.yq:

```
( .Resources[] |= 
    select(.Properties.AssumeRolePolicyDocument.Statement[].Principal.Service.[] == "ecs-tasks.amazonaws.com" or .Properties.AssumeRolePolicyDocument.Statement[].Principal.Service.[] == "lambda.amazonaws.com")
    .Properties.ManagedPolicyArns += {"Fn::ImportValue": {"!Sub": "${MyPrefix}-my-new-policy-arn"} }
)
```

command:

```
yq --from-file add_policy.yq cloudformation.yaml
```

which outputs:

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: "2010-09-09"
Parameters:
  MyPrefix:
    Description: MyPrefix
    Type: String
Resources:
  MyRole:
    Type: AWS::IAM::Role
    Properties:
      ManagedPolicyArns:
        - Fn::ImportValue: !Sub "${MyPrefix}-my-policy-arn"
        - Fn::ImportValue:
            '!Sub': ${MyPrefix}-my-new-policy-arn
      AssumeRolePolicyDocument:
        Version: '2012-10-17'
        Statement:
          - Effect: Allow
            Principal:
              Service:
                - ecs-tasks.amazonaws.com
                - lambda.amazonaws.com
            Action:
              - sts:AssumeRole
              - sts:TagSession
      Path: /
```

How do I get

```
        - Fn::ImportValue: !Sub "${MyPrefix}-my-policy-arn"
        - Fn::ImportValue: !Sub "${MyPrefix}-my-new-policy-arn"
```

instead of

```
        - Fn::ImportValue: !Sub "${MyPrefix}-my-policy-arn"
        - Fn::ImportValue:
            '!Sub': ${MyPrefix}-my-new-policy-arn
```

?

Comment: Can you confirm the yq you are using is the jq wrapper (Python based) or Go based (mikefarah/yq). Run `yq --help` to confirm

Comment: @Inian It's the Go based (https://github.com/mikefarah/yq/)

Answer (score 0):

Use the tag operator

add_policy.yq:

```
( .Resources[] |= 
    select(.Properties.AssumeRolePolicyDocument.Statement[].Principal.Service.[] == "ecs-tasks.amazonaws.com" or .Properties.AssumeRolePolicyDocument.Statement[].Principal.Service.[] == "lambda.amazonaws.com")
    .Properties.ManagedPolicyArns += {"Fn::ImportValue": "${AuthAuditBucketStackName}-logging-policy-arn" | . tag = "!Sub" }
)
```

results in:

```
- Fn::ImportValue: !Sub "${MyPrefix}-my-policy-arn"
- Fn::ImportValue: !Sub ${MyPrefix}-my-new-policy-arn
```

Now I'm not sure why the string value isn't quoted.